# Any way to make "fire and forget" API call?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nsurlconnection

I am looking to implement a relatively straight-forward feature where I make an call to an API the first time the user opens the app. However, unlike most circumstances where I am waiting for the API to provide confirmation or some information, I just want to make a "fire and forget" call and move forward with other processing.

I have explored `AFNetworking` and referencing Apple's official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests.html) on this matter, and did not discover a quick way to make fire and forget API calls. I assume this should be relatively simple to accomplish - any tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There must obviously be something missing from your question that you have omitted to mention. For example is it a networking call you are taking about (why else mention AFNetworking)? If not, then how is a regular ordinary straightforward synchronous method call without a return type not "fire and forget"? Or do you mean a broadcast? Either way, your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something about the question, if you don't care about the response, just make a normal async request with a completion handler, and leave the completion handler empty.